# Magento - the best place to place WSDL schema

Tags: magento, wsdl, payment-gateway

I'm developing the custom payment method for Magento involving the *SOAP* requests. The service provided the **wsdl** schema that I should use. But I'm struggling to decide, what would be the best place to put it following Magento module structure.

Right now I'm considering to use *etc* directory, but I have some concerns on that point, since this directory is supposed to have the *xml* config files only. Please let me know if someone has faced such issue already, and what do you consider the best architecture approach.

I know, it's not the big deal what placement I will end up with, but I would rather follow the existing pattern, if it exists...

Comment: I can't think of any analogous requirements in the magento core (but there are a heck of a lot of files in there..). I don't think its unreasonable to consider your schema file a type of config - and so there's probably no better place to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the magento core modules: app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/wsdl/FedEx

Etc directory is used for storing all configuration and service data, so you can add your wsdl file to the etc directory too.